# $m$-root in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Assume that $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$, Can we find a condition when $A$ has $m$-root
for some natural number $m$?

Comment: Relevant https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41234/torsion-in-gl-nz